# Using an if/then condition with the |> pipe character

Tags: r

I need to extract the last names of several thousand people. The names are either two or three words long, depending on whether there is a suffix or not. My attack is to count the number of words in each row, then execute a different `separate()` function depending on how many words there are. The following code does not work but shows my thinking:

```r
customers = data.frame(names=c("Jack Quinn III", "David Powell", "Carrie Green",
           "Steven Miller, Jr.", "Christine Powers", "Amanda Ramirez"))

customers |> 
  mutate(names_count = str_count(names, "\\w+")) |>
  {
  if(names_count == 2,
     separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name") ),
     separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name", "suffix") )
  )
  }
```

This code cannot possibly work because I'm missing the ability to interpret the error messages. In fact, I'm not sure if the commas are needed in the `if` statement because there are apparently functions that use both.

My thought was that I could get the names split into columns by doing

```
df |> 
  mutate() to count words |> 
  separate() to split columns based on count
```

but I can't get even the simplest if statement to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `word` from `stringr` instead:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

customers |>
    mutate(last_name = word(names, 2))
```

Output:

```r
               names last_name
1     Jack Quinn III     Quinn
2       David Powell    Powell
3       Carrie Green     Green
4 Steven Miller, Jr.   Miller,
5   Christine Powers    Powers
6     Amanda Ramirez   Ramirez
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
 customers %>%
   mutate(last_name = str_extract(names, "^[A-Za-z]+\\s+([A-Za-z]+)", group = 1))
```

-output

```
              names last_name
1     Jack Quinn III     Quinn
2       David Powell    Powell
3       Carrie Green     Green
4 Steven Miller, Jr.    Miller
5   Christine Powers    Powers
6     Amanda Ramirez   Ramirez
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `if`

```
customers %>% 
  separate(names, into = c("first_name", "last_name", "suffix"), sep=" ") %>% 
  select(last_name)
```

If you want to avoid extra packages, you can use R base `sub` + regex:

```
> sub("[A-Za-z]+\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s?.*", "\\1", customers$names)
[1] "Quinn"   "Powell"  "Green"   "Miller"  "Powers"  "Ramirez"
```